# How can I change Vim SuperTab plugin highlight color?

Tags: linux, vim, cygwin, colors, mintty

The highligthed match is basically invisible.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NuytoRP.png]

Is there any way I can change the color SuperTab uses to highlight matches? Is this perhaps a compatibility issue with my theme (molokai) or with my cursor color?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those colors are not defined by SuperTab, they are defined by your colorscheme.

To change the colors of the completion menu, open `~/.vim/colors/colorscheme_name.vim` and edit the lines starting with `hi Pmenu*`.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing me to the right direction. No need to edit those lines myself, the latest version of molokai corrects the bug, I just had to update it.